# Obtaining the results of tagged cells in a notebook from another notebook

Tags: notebooks, cells, code-request

My objective is to read the results of several tagged cells in a notebook `NB1` from another notebook `NB2`. Following the suggestions of a member of this forum, I have written the following code, which works only for a single tagged cell at a time.

```
(* I saved the following code at the bottom of NB1 (called "filename.nb"), which includes all  the tagged cells*)
ClearAll[listTags,nb];
listTags = {"Data", "Multiplier", "SectorChains"};
nb = CreateDocument@{
ExpressionCell[Defer[Print["Data"], "Input", CellTags -> {"Data"}],
ExpressionCell[Defer[Print["Multiplier"], "Input", CellTags -> {"Multiplier"}],
ExpressionCell[Defer[Print["SectorChains"], "Input", CellTags -> {"SectorChains"}] };
nb = NotebookOpen["C:\\Desktop\\filename.nb"];

(*I run the following code in `NB2` while keeping `NB1` open*)
Get["C:\\Desktop\\filename.nb"];
NotebookEvaluate[nb, EvaluationElements -> {"Tags"->{"SectorChains"}}]
```

If I want to read the results of more than one tagged cell in one run, it does not work; and `NB1` is automatically closed, generating the message: `NotebookEvaluate[] is not able to find NotebookObject[]`.

My ultimate purpose is to run it for the entire list of tags `listTags`. Furthermore, I really like to know why `NB1` is closed. Is this a bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce the errors you are describing - for me, the notebook stays open as expected. Also, what do you want to achieve with the `Get[...]` command? Isn't that double-evaluating the content of the notebook? As for your problem: Do you want to evaluate the tagged cells one-by-one, reading their results, or do you want to evaluate the whole notebook, and then read the results from cells with the appropriate tags?

Comment: @Lukas Lang: You are right about `Get[...]`. I want to evaluate the whole notebook and read the results from cells with the appropriate tags. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to only read results or do you need the procedure to evaluate appropriate cells, or the whole notebook too?

Comment: @Kuba: I can already read the results in a new notebook by `Get["file path"]` and then just type the name of the tagged cell or variable name. No problem with this procedure, however, to do that, I need to keep all the relevant files open and run them. This is a bit unnecessary for my purpose. I do not want to open the files and get the results in a new notebook. I needed a programming `procedure` to do all these hectic work for me: run necessary noteboks without opening them and import the results of interest to a new notebook.